# Spring Boot Multi Module Project, Using datasources of subproject for JPA Repository in sibling subproject

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, java-8, spring-data-jpa, multi-module

I have a complex rest api that I am deploying to AWS lambdas but managing from one code base. Spring Boot latest version with gradle.

```
Root
-\common
--\data
---JPARepositoryUser.java (Datasource 1 config)
---JPARepositoryNonUser.java (Datasource 2 config)
--build.gradle
-\subproject1
--build.gradle
-build.gradle
-settings.gradle
```

In the common submodule I have two datasources which back some Jpa repository classes in the common project.  subproject1 uses the common project as a dependency, i load it in the suproject1 build.gradle.  How do I make my JPA Repositories use the two different datasources in the common project from subproject1?  I know you have to add the @EnableJpaRepositories in the Main app class of subproject1.  But how can i specify which datasource my jpa repositories use in the subproject1?  It seems like a waste of resources to redeclare and load the datasources in the subproject1 when i already do it in common project.

Is there an annotation I can add to my "class entity extends JPARepository" in subproject1 where I specify which datasource to use from the sibling 'common' project?